# collections.Counter object for Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column reporting a certain number of cities.
I need to count the frequency of each city occurrence and put that in a `collections.Counter` object.

The dataframe is like this:

```
col1

New York
Tokyo
Tokyo
Beijing
...
```

My `collections.Counter` objects should then look something like this:
`({'New York': 1, 'Tokyo': 2, 'Beijing': 1,...})`. Is there a way to do this?

(I stress that the output has to be a `collections.Counter` object.)

Comment: `Counter(df.col1.values)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris commented, you can use use `Counter(df.col1)`:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1': ['New York', 'Tokyo', 'Tokyo', 'Beijing'] })

>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(df.col1)

Counter({'New York': 1, 'Tokyo': 2, 'Beijing': 1})
```